# How are concessions calculated?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

When somebody attacks me and he surrenders, he pays me concessions (at least with some casus bellis, such as “de jure war”).

For example, currently, I am king of Bohemia, and I am defending against the king of Hungary in “Hungarian-Bohemian De Jure War over Presspurg”. When I hover over “Enforce demands” under “Offer Peace”, it says:

> - King Szilveszter I: Lose 200.0 Prestige
> - **King Szilveszter I pays 53.6 to King Konrád II**
> - King Konrád II: Gain 100.0 Prestige from war contribution

How is the amount of money he pays me calculated? What does it depend on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, the amount of money paid depends on the size of the side doing the paying.  I'm not sure if it's linked to number of titles or size of economy, but larger empires have to pay more reparations.  (Similar to how mighty kings must pay an enormous ransom to buy an indulgence from the Pope to gain piety.)